Finding minimal translation vector to separate two overlapping convex polygons defined by linear inequalities
Given two overlapping convex polygons $P_1$ and $P_2$ in 2D plane. Each polygon is defined by a system of linear inequalities: $P_1=\{x|Ax\leq b\}$ and $P_2=\{x|Cx\leq d\}$. I want to find the minimal translation vector $\sigma$ such that when I translate $P_1$ by $\sigma$ to get $P_1'$, there is no intersection between $P_1'$ and $P_2$. In other words, I want to separate the polygons with minimal displacement $\sigma$.
\begin{equation}
\min_{\sigma} \|\sigma\|_2^2\quad\text{s.t.}\,\,P_1'\cap P_2=\varnothing\\
\text{where}\,\,P_1' = \{x\mid Ax\leq b+A\sigma\}
\end{equation}
Here is a visualization: Left: Initial overlapping polygons P1 and P2. Right: After translation, where σ is the minimal displacement vector that separates the polygons.
I feel like this is the same question as the one in Stephan Boyd's convex optimization book Separating Polyhedra (from Boyd's convex optimization page 404).
I understand that:

The dual formulation finds a separating hyperplane ($z$) between the polyhedra.
My problem requires not just separation but minimal translation

My questions is:
How can I reformulate my minimal translation problem using this duality framework?

Are you sure this can be formulated as a convex optimization problem? It seems to me you want to minimize $\sigma^2$ subject to $P1$ being satisfied and at least one row of $P2$ being violated (or vice versa). So a brute force method is to solve a separate convex optimization problem for each row of whichever of $A$ and $C$ has fewer rows in which that row is violated (i.e., reverse the inequality with an epslion margin buffer for one row of P2 if you decide to go for violation of P2). Then choose the minimum $\sigma^2$ from among those convex optimization problems.

To be clear, only the row of P2 to be violated appears in that particular convex optimization problem. The other rows of P2 are not in that problem.

Thank you Mark for pointing up this issue. In fact, I am not entirely sure if this could be formulated as a convex optimization problem or not due to my limited knowledge. My intention was to make it convex so that I could solve it efficiently. I would need to do more research on this to see how to handle this. On the other hand, your suggestion is another way to tackle this issue.

And of course I should have written $\sigma^T\sigma$, not $\sigma^2$.

I understand what you meant, and it was my fault of not using the proper notation in my problem formulation at first. Thank you again.
